# Why does migration from CVS to Mercurial fail on one machine but not another?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, repository, cvs

I'm using the following commands to convert a CVS repository to Mercurial:

```
cvs -d :pserver:<user>@<cvsroot> mymodule
hg convert mymodule
```

On an Ubuntu 12.04 machine this works, and produces a valid Mercurial repository.  On a Fedora 17 machine it spends some time working, then fails with this error:

```
...
38000 <commit message>
37930 changeset entries
sorting...
converting...
37929 Initial Checkin.
cvs server: cvs checkout: cannot find module `mymodule/<cvsroot>/<some file>` - ignored
abort: unknown CVS response: error
```

Edit: I overlooked this at first, but the path that it cannot find is a little funny; it consists of the module name followed by the CVSROOT and actual path.

Both machines have identical .hgrc files and are both running CVS 1.12.13.  The only environment variable that seems relevant is CVSROOT, which is the same on both machines and set to the same value as my `<cvsroot>` placeholder above.

The file that produces the error is the same every time, but it's a perfectly normal file; I can't identify anything that differentiates it from any other file.

Just to be clear, I know that I could simply use the working machine, and I know that there are many other tools, like cvs2svn[hg] that also do repository conversion.  But I'm not interested in that; I want to understand this specific problem.

Why does conversion of the same repository fail on different machines, and what are some strategies for debugging this further?

Comment: Out of disk space on Fedora machine?

Comment: Good question! I don't think so, though; it has 13+GB free after generating the ~26MB cvsps cache, and the repo should not require close to that much space.

Comment: Next, I would prepend your command with `strace` to follow system calls and signals and see if there's an error there.   `strace hg convert mymodule`

Comment: I didn't see anything out of the ordinary in the strace output; it send()s the CVS command, and receives the error that it then prints out.  While doing that I did notice something funny about the path that's logged in the error: see my edit above.

Comment: At this point, I don't know enough about Mercurial, hg, or `hg convert` so can't comment on that.

Comment: Why do you care?  If you can convert it just convert all your repos and then start using Hg.  Conversion needs to only happen once

Comment: I knew that, despite my explicit disclaimer, someone would come along who can't comprehend the idea of wanting to understand why something behaves a certain way independently of solving a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the Ubuntu machine had an existing checkout of that repository, which was originally checked out using a `<cvsroot>` specified as `<server>:/<path>/`.  The command I used specified it as `<server>/<path>/`, without the colon.

CVS accepts both forms - with and without the colon - but but there's a particular function in hg convert's cvsps.py that assumes the former.  If the repository was originally checked out without the colon, hg convert doesn't properly strip prefixes from filenames.  This eventually results in it using the wrong path, as I noticed in the error message, when it tries to pull down file revisions.

So it worked on the Ubuntu machine because it had originally been checked out with a colon, and subsequent checkouts using the non-colon form were simply updating it without changing the contents of /CVS/Root, the file that hg convert reads to find the root.

All I had to do to get the other machine working was to rm the repository and check it out clean using a cvsroot containing a colon between the server and path.

Comment: After looking through the source, it appears that this is actually a bug in Mercurial's CVS conversion module; I've filed it (#3678) in their bug tracker.